# Observer Pattern (C++): Cast Templated Class from Subclass to Baseclass of Tempalate

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, observer-pattern

I am working on developing an observer pattern infrastructure and was hoping to get some advice on a design issue I have run into. The idea behind this pattern is to allow users to create "Transactions" from any primitive type they would like. Users can then develop their own custom Observers to do things like logging / build statistics / etc... Everything is then hooked up at runtime using factory methods depending on what they would like based on a configuration. This all works really well, until a user would like to provide a baseclass pointer based observer and have it work for all derived types. When observers are added I check if the types match and throw an exception if it is the wrong type.

Below is a simple example of the pattern and the use case that is breaking it.

Thanks so much in advance!

```
#include <cassert>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> 
class Observerable;

template<typename T> 
struct ObserverInfo {
    const T& data;
    const Observerable<T>& observer;
};

class IObserver {
public:
    virtual ~IObserver() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Observer : public IObserver {
public:
    virtual void Annouce(const ObserverInfo<T>& info);

}; 

class DumperBase {
public:
    virtual void Dump() const = 0;

};

class MyTransaction : public DumperBase {
public:
    void Dump() const override { printf("Hello\n"); }
};


class IObserverable {
public:
    virtual ~IObserverable() {}
    virtual void AttachObserver(IObserver* observer) = 0;
};



template<typename T>
class Observerable : public IObserverable {
public:
    void AttachObserver(IObserver* observer) override {
        // ?? Is there a way I can make this work for base clases?
        auto casted_observer = dynamic_cast<Observer<T>*>(observer);
        assert(casted_observer);
        m_observers.emplace_back(casted_observer);
    }

    void Push(T transaction) {
        Annouce({transaction, *this});
        // Do something real with T
    }

    void Annouce(const ObserverInfo<T>& info) {
        for (auto& observer : m_observers) {
            observer->Annouce(info); 
        }
    } 

private:
    std::vector<Observer<T>*> m_observers;
};

class MyTransactionObserver : public Observer<DumperBase*> {
    void Annouce(const ObserverInfo<DumperBase*>& info) override {
        info.data->Dump();
    }
};


int main() {

    Observerable<MyTransaction*> observerable{};
    Observer<DumperBase*> observer{};
    observerable.AttachObserver(&observer);

    MyTransaction transaction{};
    observerable.Push(&transaction);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Observer<DumperBase*>::Annouce` takes `ObserverInfo<DumperBase*>` as a parameter. That has a member of type `Observerable<DumperBase*>&`. What are you planning to bind to that reference? Your program doesn't ever instantiate an object of that type. Note that `Observerable<MyTransaction*>` is not derived from, and in general is unrelated to, `Observerable<DumperBase*>` . Even though `MyTransaction*` is convertible to `DumperBase*`, the fact is that `Observerable<MyTransaction*>` is not convertible to `Observerable<DumperBase*>`

Comment: This was kind of my question. Is there a design pattern for this approach? I was thinking could have the observer attach a std:: function but that may run into the same issue?

Comment: Are you talking about double dispatch? That is, the code does something different depending on the observer type (log, stats, etc) and the observable type? That's typically solved by the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)